# MySql & Python problem : author found one by one but not inside function

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, set

I'm aiming to automate the insertion of book metadata in a mysql database.

I'm working on creating a dictionary based on a set of authors, so I can later replace, with the dictionary, the author by its author_id in every book object having this particular author in its author field. This way, my data will be prepared for its insertion in the database.

My example set being

```
authors_set = {'Maurice Blanchot', 'Paul Celan', 'Jean-Pierre Martinet', 'Yves Citton'}
```

I'm trying this:

```py
AUTHOR_EXISTENCE = "SELECT id, full_name FROM authors WHERE full_name = %s"

def create_dict(iterable, query):
    dictionary = {}
    mysql_db = ms.connect(**mysql_conn_params)
    cur = mysql_db.cursor(buffered=True)        
    for author in iterable:
        if cur.execute(query, [author]):
            for id, value in cur:
                dictionary[value] = id
        else:
            dictionary[author] = author
    return dictionary

authors_dict = create_dict(authors_set, AUTHOR_EXISTENCE)
```

Which never returns anything, although I know at least one author should be in the dictionary. I don't see what I'm doing different from the [MySql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html).

**EDIT:**
When I am printing `cur` after `cur.execute(query, [author])`, my terminal prints:
`MySQLCursorBuffered: SELECT id, full_name FROM authors WHERE ..`
I guess I should see the authors name at the end. My code doesn't look wrong to my eye though. Must be somehow.
**END EDIT**

But I have tried something which worked each time I'm searching for one author only:

```
mysql_db = ms.connect(**mysql_conn_params)
cur = mysql_db.cursor(buffered=True)
cur.execute(AUTHOR_EXISTENCE, ['Yves Citton'])
for id, value in cur:
    print(id, value)
```

And it returns : `2 Yves Citton`, like it should.

Somehow neither the nice MySql documentation, my searches nor my knowledge gave me a clue about the solution.

Could anyone help me ?
Thank you for your attention

Comment: The `else` clause looks like a problem.  If no author has returned a result so far, it will fail because `value` is undefined.  If a previous author returned a result but this one didn't, it will "work" but give a strange result (because `value` is left over from the previous iteration).

Comment: @slothrop Thank you for pointing this out : I switched the two "value" by author in the else clause to see what would happen (I'll edit it in the question) — and the result is that the `if` clause doesn't seem to "work" at all : my dictionary is filled with values identical to their keys. It wasn't filling before — but now I have to think about why that `if` clause is never truthy.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution, even if I can't quite tell the difference : I wrote the "execute" part with a tuple for value instead of a list, and I deleted the else clause because I'm creating the dictionary after all authors are inserted in the database.

```
def create_dictionary(query, iterable):
    dictionary = {}
    connexion =  ms.connect(**mysql_conn_params)
    cursor = connexion.cursor(buffered=True)

    for value in iterable:
        cursor.execute(query, (value, )) #change is here
        for id, name in cursor:
            dictionary[name] = id

    connexion.close()
    return dictionary
```